# Google Guice. I need to inject correspoding parent object to contained objects

Tags: guice

Sry for my english. I have next problem. I have three entities:
DomainManager, Domain and Node. DomainManager is singleton that able
to create list of Domain objects. Each Domain can create list of Node
objects:

DomainManager 1<>-----* Domain 1<>----* Node

I want:

1. Node implementation can inject corresponding parent Domain to
   himself.
2. Node implementation can inject Domain manager instance too.

class NodeImpl {
   @Inject
   NodeImpl(Domain parentDomain, DomainManager domainManager) {

}
}

How can i do this?

Comment: You probably want to take a look at Guice "assisted injection".

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without knowing exactly what you want to **do** with your Nodes and Domains but, following jfpoilpret's (+1) advice using @Assisted injected parameters might help you.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791423/inject-the-same-component-with-different-parameters-with-guice) or (even better) [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject) for details of how this works.

Having said that, your constructor for NodeImpl might look like this:

```
@Inject
public NodeImpl(DomainManager manager, @Assisted Domain) {}
```

You then create a NodeFactory to hand back instances of NodeImpl.  However, you still need something that **uses** the NodeFactory to figure out which Nodes are associated with which Domains.