# Guice:Binding Annotations with Attributes

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, guice

Now I am reading Guice's official document, but I have some questions related to the chapter of Binding Annotation.

[This](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) explains "Annotation with Attributes".  But, I'm not sure of the explanation.

> Binding Annotations with Attributes
>
> Guice supports binding annotations that have attribute values. In the
>   rare case that you need such an annotation:
>
> Create the annotation @interface. Create a class that implements the
>   annotation interface. Follow the guidelines for equals() and
>   hashCode() specified in the Annotation Javadoc. Pass an instance of
>   this to the annotatedWith() binding clause.

I don't understand that explanation.   For what is the explanation intended?  I learned two annotations such as @Paypal(in this document) and @name.  But perhaps we can't achieve only with these two annotations when I want to use some dependencies more than two toward a same class?
Now I am confused, could anyone explain?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704918/custom-guice-binding-annotations-with-parameters The answer here is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guice figures out what you want to inject by using a [`Key`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Key.html), which is just a name for the combination of *a binding annotation* (an annotation that itself is annotated with [`@BindingAnnotation`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/BindingAnnotation.html) or [`@Qualifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Qualifier.html)) and *a type* (with parameters if needed). These are all valid keys, distinct from one another:

- `YourClassOne`
- `YourClassTwo`
- `List<Integer>`
- `List<String>`
- `@Paypal YourClassOne`
- `@Paypal YourClassTwo`
- `@YourBindingAnnotation YourClassOne`
- `@YourBindingAnnotation List<String>`

However, annotations are allowed to have attributes, like with [`@Named("your name here")`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/name/Named.html). This means that keys differ not only on which binding annotation you have, but what its attributes are. Let's add some keys using *annotations with attributes* to the list above:

- `@Named("foo") YourClassOne`
- `@Named("bar") YourClassOne`
- `@AnotherBindingAnnotation(foo=3, bar=5) YourClassOne`
- `@AnotherBindingAnnotation(foo=6, bar=1) YourClassOne`

They're all different from one another, and they're all valid things to provide to Guice and inject from Guice.

**In general, you probably don't need to create your own binding annotations with attributes:** Binding annotations are not that common in the first place, and most cases where you want them can be handled with empty (no-attribute) binding annotations or use of the built-in `@Named` annotation (along with its counterpart, [`Names.named`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/name/Names.html#named-java.lang.String-), which helps you create a compatible *instance of your annotation* that you can use in your AbstractModule). However, if you DO want to create your own binding annotation with attributes, you can use the part of the docs you quoted in order to create that, particularly in conforming to the [Annotation.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) and [Annotation.hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#hashCode--) requirements. (If this is something you expect to do a lot, consider using a library like [Apache Commons AnnotationUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/AnnotationUtils.html) or a code generator like [Google Auto's AutoAnnotation](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/howto.md#annotation).)

Comment: Thanks.  You and the document explained `Key` is just a name for combination of both an annotation and a type.  For example, `@Paypal CreditCardProcessor` has the annotation `@Paypal` and the type `CreditCardProcessor`.  In your explanation, are these four Strings `Key`s?  `YourClassOne`, `YourClassTwo`, `List<Integer>`, `List<String>` despite no annotation.

Comment: Yes, a type without an annotation can still be a Key. Note that the ones I listed are not Strings—you'll typically just see the type and annotation as a field or a constructor parameter, but if you manually create a Key using one of its factory methods you'll need to pass in a Type object (usually a Class or a TypeLiteral).